# Loading an unordered map

Tags: c++, hashmap, fstream

I have a file with a lot of words that i'm trying to read and store. I'm trying to create sort a map.

I declared a struct at the beginning of the program which is supposed to be used to store the information for a each entry.

```
typedef struct dictionary{ std::string word; unsigned char * hash; char *hex; } a_dictionary;
unordered_map<char * , a_dictionary * > Mymap;
```

THis is the code that i'm performing to save the words, but for some reason myMap doesn't get properly written

```
if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER freq, before, after;
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&before);
            while ( myfile.good() )
            {
                getline (myfile,line);

                a_dictionary * dic = new dictionary(); // after each line create
                dic->word = line;


                const char * c= line.c_str();
                sha1::calc(c,line.length(), hash);//encrypts the word

                dic->hash = hash;

                sha1::toHexString(hash,hex_str);//encrypts the word
                dic->hex = hex_str;

                Mymap.insert(std::make_pair(hex_str, dic));
            }
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&after);
            float fElapsed = static_cast<float>(after.QuadPart - before.QuadPart) / freq.QuadPart;
            cout<<"Finished in "<<fElapsed;
```

I don't get any compile errors, and when i output the variables for the struct inside the while loop they come out ok...but my unordered_map never gets filled.

Comment: It looks like you're using the same hex_str and hash every single time...every dic object is holding a pointer to the same hash and hex_str, so every call to Mymap.insert is using the same key. If you checked the return value of Mymap.insert, it would be a pair of an iterator into Mymap (probably Mymap.begin(), if this is the only place you're inserting into Mymap) and false, the latter of which indicates that there is no insertion due to a duplicate key.

Comment: You probably want to wrap hash and hex_str with either std::string or std::vector<char>

Comment: but i thougt by declaring new, i would be creating a new instance of the struct

Comment: yes, of the struct. but there's only one hash and hex_str...every dic object you create will be storing the same pointers, and you'll be overriding the same buffers in every loop.

Comment: i think you messed up the code formatting with your edit by omitting a newline (I would edit it but it will get queue since my reputation is not high enough)...can you fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, it looks like the same *hash* and *hex_str* buffers are being reused in every iteration of the loop, so you're using the same key every time (the pointer address is being used as the key, not the string contents)

Without knowing the signatures of *sha1::calc* and *sha1::hash* or how you've declared *hash* and *hex_str*, I'm going to assume you're using them correctly as-is (I'm guessing they're c-arrays and the functions take pointers to buffers and do not null-terminate the output), the minimal change I would make would be something like following:

**Definitions:**

```
// no typedef necessary for struct in C++
struct dictionary {
    std::string word;
    std::vector<unsigned char> hash;
    // string instead of vector so it's hashable
    std::string hex;
};
std::unordered_map<std::string, dictionary*> Mymap;
```

**Implementation:**

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    LARGE_INTEGER freq, before, after;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&before);
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        getline (myfile,line);

        dictionary * dic = new dictionary(); // after each line create
        dic->word = line;

        const char * c= line.c_str();

        dic->hash.resize(SIZE_OF_HASH_BUFFER);
        sha1::calc(c, line.length(), &(dic->hash[0]));//encrypts the word

        dic->hex.resize(SIZE_OF_HEX_STR_BUFFER);
        sha1::toHexString(&(dic->hash[0]), &(dic->hex[0]));//encrypts the word

        if(!(Mymap.insert(std::make_pair(dic->hex, dic)).second))
        {
            // handle collision somehow...
        }
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&after);
    float fElapsed = static_cast<float>(after.QuadPart - before.QuadPart) / freq.QuadPart;
    cout<<"Finished in "<<fElapsed;
```

Depending on how you're using *Mymap*, you might want to wrap dictionary objects in smart pointers, or maybe just have them passed by value...can't really say without more context. Right now, you definitely need to make sure you deallocate the memory associated with each dictionary after you're done with the contents of *Mymap*...if that's what you really want instead of having it done for you automatically with a smart pointer, you can, but you have to be careful to clean up.

Comment: on your hash.insert, and hex.insert it says that there is no instance of overloaded function

Comment: I think I fixed that (also switched to assign rather than insert)...try now

Comment: the std::pair<Myma..doesn't compile

Comment: it says that name followed by:: must be a namespace or struct

Comment: sorry, should be "std::unordered_map<std::vector<unsigned char>, dictionary *>::iterator", thought Mymap was the type. Anyway, you might not need the iterator anyway so I got rid of it. It would be easier if you're using C++11 since you can just use "auto" then, but I'm not sure if you are.

Comment: I also got rid of the intermediate buffers completely but I don't know their size, so you'd have to fill that in.

Comment: Sorry, realized begin() might not actually be the raw pointer type, so changed that too.

Comment: So just replace the type with auto and it'll be inferrred. Or you can just use what I have above: map::insert will return a pair of iterator and a bool, the second is false if there's a collision (i.e. nothing got inserted). So it depends on what you want to do if there's a collision, and if that will requiring having an iterator into the existing value.

Comment: where r u saving dic->hash and  dic-hex

Comment: ? They're data members of dictionary. They're vector, so internally they store pointers into a dynamically allocated array on the heap, but that's implementation detail.

Comment: Did you change dlc->hash.begin() to &(dic->hash[0])?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25191/discussion-between-stephen-lin-and-user1665569)